# Is it possible to define a responsive container with PrimeNg?

Tags: css, primeng

I am looking for the **PrimeNg**'s equivalent of the **Bootstrap**'s `.container` class, so my elements can have a reasonable `max-width` on large or extra large devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally defined it myself:

```
.container { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { .container { max-width: 100%; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { .container { max-width: 740px; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) { .container { max-width: 980px; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) { .container { max-width: 1140px; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 1400px) { .container { max-width: 1320px; } }
```

It has the advantage to let you adjust the values to your convenience.